# HTACCESS - Change title

Tags: php, .htaccess

Is there anyway to let the page "home.php" show as "overview" without file extension and change the title too?

A pretty small question!

Comment: Yes, there is. A pretty small answer!

Comment: Can you please explain? A pretty small reply!

Comment: @u_mulder The anticipation is killing me

Comment: Change your links to `overview` and have `overview` rewrite to `home.php`.